# Internet File Saving: Automatically add sequence number to files with identical names

Tags: windows

When saving pictures from the web with the same name, these no longer get auto-renamed with a sequential number.

It *used* to, long ago, but, alas, no longer, this feature was removed.

It is most likely still within Windows, just not activated.

If not, is there a Firefox/Edge extension or application that can do this?

How do I fix this, please?